# Bitcoins deducted from Multibit wallet but nothing was sent

Tags: wallet, blockchain.info, multibit, sending

I sent 1 bitcoin FROM Multibit wallet TO this address `19xQJNmK3Ys4pXwMh11mwdfky4wNsNDj1Z`.

The transaction was stuck at `"Seen by 1 peer, not confirmed"` for more than 7 hours.

Checking [blockchain.info](https://blockchain.info/address/19xQJNmK3Ys4pXwMh11mwdfky4wNsNDj1Z) it seems that the transaction was never sent

Based on [Multibit documentation regarding stuck transaction](https://multibit.org/en/help/v0.5/help_support_sentBitcoinFromMultibitButTheyAreStuck.html) I tried to reset blockchain and transactions that never made it. Needless to say I ended up with 1 bitcoin LESS in my balance, and the transaction did not appear either in Multibit or in blockchain.info.

Any clues? thanks in advance.

Edit1: A typical fee for a transaction is 0.0001 (0.1 mBTC), that is set automatically by Multibit and can't be altered.

Comment: The first couple of times I was resetting it to previous day or two. It should have fixed the problem but it didn't.

Resetting transactions completely seems to have fixed the issue, though. phew...